# error[E0597]: borrowed value does not live long enough in While loop

Tags: rust

I am really new to Rust, I am having trouble solving this error, but it only happens if I comment out the while statement , basicly I am asking values from the console and storing it in a HashMap:

```
use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::io;

fn main() {
    let mut customers = HashMap::new();
    let mut next_customer = true;
    while next_customer {
        let mut input_string = String::new();
        let mut temp_vec = Vec::with_capacity(3);
        let mut vec = Vec::with_capacity(2);
        println!("Insert new customer f.e = customer id,name,address:");
        io::stdin().read_line(&mut input_string);
        input_string = input_string.trim().to_string();
        for s in input_string.split(",") {
            temp_vec.push(s);
        }
        vec.push(temp_vec[1]);
        vec.push(temp_vec[2]);
        let mut key_value = temp_vec[0].parse::<i32>().unwrap();
        customers.insert(key_value, vec);
        next_customer = false;
    }
    println!("DONE");
}
```

The code results in the error

```
error[E0597]: `input_string` does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:14:18
   |
14 |         for s in input_string.split(",") {
   |                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^ borrowed value does not live long enough
...
20 |         customers.insert(key_value, vec);
   |         --------- borrow later used here
21 |         next_customer = false;
22 |     }
   |     - `input_string` dropped here while still borrowed
```

Comment: Basically, `vec` ends up containing references to slices of `input_string`, which only lives until the end of the loop iteration, but you try to add it to `customers`, which outlives the loop.

Comment: try this: `input_string.split(",").collect()` https://users.rust-lang.org/t/solved-string-lifetime-error-borrowed-value-does-not-live-long-enough/5233

Comment: I'd suggest `vec.push(temp_vec[1].to_owned())`, and similar for the following line.

Comment: @sven-marnach this worked for me but not sure why

Comment: @SvenMarnach how those "vec ends up containing references to slices of input_string" I dont see it assing to it or anything

Comment: The `trim()` and `split()` methods don't allocate new strings – they return slice references pointing into the string you passed in, i.e. the return values have type `&str` rather than `String`. The slices only live as ong as the string they are pointing to, which is until the end of the loop iteration in this case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As others have said the problem lies with the lifetime and/or type of the values getting put into the customers map.

```
customers.insert(key_value, vec);
   |         --------- borrow later used here
```

Often this happens when the compiler has decided to give an object a type that you didn't expect. To find out what it's doing you can force the type, and see how it complains. Changing the code to:

```
    let mut customers: HashMap<(),()> = HashMap::new();
```

Gives us two relevant errors:

```
20 |         customers.insert(key_value, vec);
   |                          ^^^^^^^^^ expected `()`, found `i32`
...
20 |         customers.insert(key_value, vec);
   |                                     ^^^ expected `()`, found struct `std::vec::Vec`
   |
   = note: expected unit type `()`
                 found struct `std::vec::Vec<&str>`
```

So the type that the compiler wants to give our customers object is `HashMap<i32, Vec<&str>>`

The problem is that the `&str` lifetime has got to be inside the block as we don't store the `String`s anywhere, and they can't have `'static` lifetime since they're user input.

This means we probably want a `HashMap<i32,Vec<String>>`.

Changing the code to use one of those gives us an error about `vec` not having the right type: It's getting deduced as a `Vec<&str>`, but we want a `Vec<String>`.

We have two options.

1. Convert the vec to the right type just before we insert it into the map using `customers.insert(key_value, vec.iter().map(|s| s.to_string()).collect())`. (Though you may want to extract it to a variable for clarity).
2. Explicitly change the type of vec to `Vec<String>`

Option 1 "just works". While option 2 leads us down a path of making similar changes closer and closer to the `read_line` call.

Once you've decided on the fix in option 1, you can remove the manual type annotations that were added to work out the fix, if you find them overly noisy.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that you are passing around reference to underlying &str values that will get dropped.  One way is to take the input string, trim and split it, then clone it going into the other vector.

```rust
let temp_vec: Vec<String> = input_string.trim().split(",").map(|t| t.to_string()).collect();
vec.push(temp_vec[1].clone());
vec.push(temp_vec[2].clone());
```

Comment: This worked for me aswell but not sure how it works the first line of temp_vec, im just new to rust, i will investigated and understand it, thanks

Comment: So basically, the input_string gets trimmed and split.  The split then has a bunch of &str slices.  We then convert those &str slices to full Strings.  These strings are then collected into a vector.  You can't move stuff out of a vector trivially, so we just clone (creating a new String copy) and let that go into the new vec that gets placed in the map.  This way vec owns the new cloned strings.